# Is there a security standard/framework which interpret the CISO role as independent position

Tags: iso27001, nist

It is more or less an open secret that the CISO should act independently in the company.  In my opinion, a supposed reporting line to the CIO is a conflict of interest (budget vs. security).
The CISO should be independent of influence or pressure from those involved in the day-to-day protection or purchase of corporate assets.

Is there any security related standard like ISO, NIST which supports this thesis?

Comment: hi and welcome to the site. Could you further narrow down your question to a specific standard? ISO and NIST both are organizations that give out a large bandwidth of standards, some of them are security related. Afaik the ISO27000 series does not make a statement in the form "A CISO must be independent from the CIO" because it does not speak of such specific roles.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, no standard explicitly requires the CISO to be independent of influence. You might mix this in your head with the privacy officer in Europe who has such a requirement.

In ISO 27001, the role CISO is never mentioned (at least in the versions I have, don't forget that there's a new one every few years). In fact, A 6.1.1 where roles and responsibilities are required to be defined doesn't even mention independence or anything remotely like it. And A 6.1.2 where segregation of duties is mentioned does this in the context of preventing unauthorized access, not in the context of CISO independence.

Now if we look into ISO 27002, we find "a security manager" as the closest that ISO comes to naming the CISO. However, this is not in the control, not even in the implementation guidance, but under "other information" which is totally non-binding and not even a recommendation. Again, 6.1.1 does not required independence, doesn't even recommend it, doesn't even mention it.

For NIST I have only the framework summary here, but again it doesn't contain the word CISO and while it also defines roles and responsibilities (ID.AM-6 and other places), I can't find an explicit requirement of independence.

And this is all good and well because not only is the CISO different in each organisation, we don't even need to have one. It is a common practice and yes, it is fairly common that he is not in the IT department, but that isn't a must nor is it globally true. I've worked with CISOs who are in the IT department, I've had one CISO who was also the CIO and other weird setups. Whatever works for the organisation, you know?

As an auditor (for ISO 27001 in my case), I would not expect the CISO to be independent organisationally, though it is a common case. I wouldn't specifically mention conflict of interest either, as it's not a concern in ISO 27001. However, if I see that this might be an issue, I would look closely at the risk treatment process and the evidence of risk treatment to see if security concerns are overshadowed by other interests and if any gaps I notice can be explained by the risk criteria and security objectives the organisation has defined.

---

All that said, I have been a CISO with independence like you describe (reporting to the CFO) but that was a historic artifact - the position came into being as a consequence of SOX requirements, which is a **compliance** standard, not a security standard. From this perspective, independence is much more common. However, even SOX does not proscribe it. Most of the implementation guidances for SOX do, but the law itself doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I challenge your assertion that the CISO must be independent. There is no requirement or definition for this.

You might have flipped the logic around in your head. A CISO with certain reporting structures can have pressures which can compromise security strategy. But that does not mean that the CISO must then be independent.

CISOs report to someone. Always. CISOs support the work of the organisation. The question is whether the reporting structure is working in favour of the organisation or not. And that's determined by the organisation and not a standard.